# Unit Test without Demo Data in odoo

Tags: python, unit-testing, odoo, odoo-12

Can I actually run a unit test without mark 'load demo data' on my database? If yes, what are the consequences? What are the best practises for unit testing? Can you do testing on your actual database? I'm using odoo12 and now working on unit test2 for python codes. Please help me with this matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can run test without demo data. If you run odoo with `--test-enable` then odoo runs test for all installed and updated modules. (`-u ...`)

I believe stock test are failing if you don't have demo data installed.

Never run tests in production database it will leave marks on the database.

I am running tests in isolation and without demo data. But i am running own tests only.

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/testing.html

Comment: Can you please explain how do you mean by running test in isolation?

Comment: i am using `-u module_name` when i test, that way i am running only the tests for that module. If i have empty base then i am using `-i module_name` first to install all the dependencies for my module, and then i run the test command. There is also `--test-tags` where you can include or exclude tests.